# Unable to copy data from one Hive table to another HIve table within same database

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am trying to copy data from one to table to another table of default database in hive but hadoop is just stuck in processing. I waited for few hours but no luck.

Here I am trying to copy data from employee table to employee2 within default database and it has no partitions.This is the create query I have used for both the tables

```
create table employee(id int,name string,dept string,salary bigint)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'  
stored as TextFile;
```

Below is the command used for copying data from one table to another

> INSERT OVERWRITE table employee2
> SELECT * FROM employee ;

I get this and afterwards it is stuck.

> hive> INSERT OVERWRITE table employee2
> SELECT * FROM employee ;
> Query ID = chivid_20170413135151_73c1ac36-1d1c-4ef4-aabe-c150aa487ae7
> Total jobs = 3
>
> Launching Job 1 out of 3
>
> Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator

please let me know where I am going wrong and I could find only similar commands with partitions for copying data in one of the SO question.

Comment: send these values from yarn properties yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb

Comment: Also, inspect the status of the job in YARN UI -- if you don't have enough free RAM to allocate 2 containers, then your job will stay in ACCEPTED mode forever.

Comment: check YARN UI, whether this job is in the right QUEUE .